# Search specific areas in PDF form

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I think that I have a tall ask!

[image: Uniform Residential Appraisal Report - Freddie Mac Form 70/Fannie Mae Form 1004]

I am attempting to use VBA to search through a PDF form for specific aspects in order to fill out a checklist.  For example, I want to be able to find out what kind of "Assignment Type", "Property Rights Appraised", if it is a "PUD", etc.  Here is the [full form](https://sf.freddiemac.com/content/_assets/resources/pdf/forms/70.pdf), it is a standardized form, so most things are the same for each appraisal.

The only things I can find to do is [search for words in a PDF](https://software-solutions-online.com/how-to-search-a-pdf-for-a-string-using-vba-for-excel/) or [count the number of pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015108/how-to-get-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-document-using-vba), that is about it.  Is VBA too limited?  Do I need to use a different program, like python?  Below is what I have so far, it is not much, and I do have access to Adobe Acrobat, just not on the computer I began typing my code on.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Run_Worksheet()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim FileChosen As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tw As ThisWorkbook: Set tw = ThisWorkbook
    Dim AcroDoc As Object
    Dim Pgnum As Long
    Set AcroDoc = New AcroApp

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.InitialFileName = "Desktop"
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

    FileChosen = fd.Show
    If FileChosen = -1 Then
        For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count

            tw.FollowHyperlink (fd.SelectedItems(i))

        Next i
    End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would have to convert the PDF to something else to parse it, and you are right, that is no simple task.

Comment: @braX do you thing doing a "Save As" `.xlsx` file could do the trick?

Comment: PDF is no structured data format. Imagine PDF literally as a sheet of paper (this is what PDF was invented for, being a digital sheet of paper). So if you can imagine how dificult it would be to search on a specifc area of a sheet of paper, the same difficulty occurs when searching in an area of a PDF. • Any tricks like convert PDF into any other (structured) format like Excel or Word might help in this specific PDF file but if the file changes only a bit that can easily end up in a mess. • If it can be done it is *at least* on an advancded level.

Comment: I just tried saving it as a Word Doc and it allows me to search for things such as "X Owner" and "X Refinance Transaction".  I will attempt to build it that way.  Thanks for the direction! @Pᴇʜ